# RecyclerView Não carrega na tela

Tags: java, android

O meu recycler view não aparece na tela se alguém puder ajudar agradeço eu sou iniciante daí estou com dificuldades, porém eu consegui fazer outros dois só esse que tá me tirando o sono :/
Muito obrigada =]

MEU ADAPTER

```
public class DiasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiasAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<Dia> dias;
        Context context;
        DiasListner diasListner;
//private RecyclerViewClickListener listener;


           public DiasAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Dia> dias, DiasListner diasListner) {
            this.context = context;
            this.dias = dias;
            this.diasListner = diasListner;

        }


        //Aqui cria as visualizações
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
//Criação da view

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_dias, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }



    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Dia dia = dias.get(position);

        holder.imageCalendarioEnsaio.setImageResource(dia.getImgDias());

        holder.textViewDiasSemana.setText(dia.getNomeDias());

        //Pegando ação do clique do usuário na lista

//Pegando ação do clique do usuário na lista
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                diasListner.addDia(dia );

            }
        });
//Seta imagem

        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }




        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dias.size();
        }


        //Esssa classe MY VIEWHOLDER é responsável por guardar os dados antes de eles serem exibidos na tela
        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
               //INICILIZA VARIAVEL
            ImageView imageCalendarioEnsaio;
            TextView textViewDiasSemana;


            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                imageCalendarioEnsaio = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageCalendarioEnsaio);
                textViewDiasSemana = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDiasSemana);
            }
        }
}
```

MEU LISTENER

```
public interface DiasListner {
    public void addDia(Dia dia);
}
```

Classe principal

```
package com.example.tocacomigo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.tocacomigo.activity.Estilo;
import com.example.tocacomigo.adapter.DiasAdapter;
import com.example.tocacomigo.adapter.EstilosAdapter;
import com.example.tocacomigo.adapter.InstrumentosAdapter;
import com.example.tocacomigo.listner.DiasListner;
import com.example.tocacomigo.listner.EstilosListner;
import com.example.tocacomigo.listner.InstrumentoListner;
import com.example.tocacomigo.model.Musico;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class FinalizaCadastro extends AppCompatActivity implements InstrumentoListner, EstilosListner, DiasListner {

    //Recycler DIAS ENSAIO------------------------------------------
    RecyclerView recyclerViewDias;
    ArrayList<Dia> dias;
    DiasAdapter diasAdapter;
    private List<String> diasString;

    //Recycler ESTILOS MUSICAIS------------------------------------------
    RecyclerView recyclerViewEstilos;
    ArrayList<Estilo> estilos;
    EstilosAdapter estilosAdapter;
    private List<String> estilosString;


    //---------------------------INSTRUMENTOS-------------------------------------------
    RecyclerView recyclerViewInstrumentos;
    ArrayList<Instrumento> instrumentos;
    InstrumentosAdapter adapter_instrumentos;
    private List<String> instrumentosString;


    //Variaveis de Localização ------------
    Button btnLocalizacaoMusico, btnFinalizarCadastro;
    TextView textViewLocalizacao, textView1, textView2, textView4, textView6;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    //----REFERENTE A DATA DE NASCIMENTO---------------
    Button btnCalendario;
    TextView textDataNasc, textIdade;

    //----------------FIREBASE----------
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseDatabase database;


    private Musico musico;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finalizarcadastro);


        //----FIREBASE-----------------------------------

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


        //-----------------------------------------------------------ESTILOS---------------------
        recyclerViewEstilos = findViewById(R.id.recyclerEstilos);
        recyclerViewDias = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDias);
        recyclerViewInstrumentos = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewInstrumentos);


        //---------------------CRIANDO STRING DE ARRAYS DE ESTILOS ------


        String[] nomeEstilo = {"Axé", "Black Music", "Blues", "Bossa Nova", "Chillout", "Classic Rock", "Clássico", "Country", "Dance", "Disco", "Electro Swing", "Electronica", "Emocore", "Fado", "Folk", "Forró", "Funk", "Funk Carioca", "Gospel/Religioso", "Gótico", "Grunge", "Hard Rock", "Hardcore", "Heavy Metal", "Hip Hop", "House", "Indie", "industrial", "infantil", "instrumental", "j-pop", "Jazz", "jovem Guarda", "K Pop", "Kizomba", "Metal", "MPB", "Músicas Gaúchas", "New Age", "New Wave", "Pagode", "Paino Rock", "Pop", "Pop/Funk", "Pop/Rock", "Pós Punk", "Post Rock", "Power Pop", "Progressivo", "Psicodelia", "Punk Rock", "R&B", "Rap", "Reggae", "Reggaeton", "Regional", "Rock", "Rock Alternativo", "Rockabilly", "Romântico", "Samba", "Samba Enredo", "Sertanejo", "Ska", "Soft Rock", "Soul Music", "Surf Music", "Tecnopop", "Trance", "Trap", "Trilha Sonora", "Trip Hop", "Tropical House", "Velha Guarda", "World Music",
        };


        //---------------------------ESTILO--------------------------------------------------
        //Inicializando o arrayList

        estilos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nomeEstilo.length; i++) {
            Estilo estiloM = new Estilo(nomeEstilo[i]);
            estilos.add(estiloM);
        }

        //Design horizontal ESTILO-------------------------------------------

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerEstiloM = new LinearLayoutManager(
                FinalizaCadastro.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false
        );

        recyclerViewEstilos.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerEstiloM);
        recyclerViewEstilos.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        //Inicializa EstilosAdapter------------------------------------------------ESTILOS

        estilosAdapter = new EstilosAdapter(FinalizaCadastro.this, estilos, this);
        //Seta adapter para RecyclerView

        recyclerViewEstilos.setAdapter(estilosAdapter);


        musico = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("musico");

        //Localização
        btnLocalizacaoMusico = findViewById(R.id.btnLocalizacaoMusico);
        btnFinalizarCadastro = findViewById(R.id.btnFinalizarCadastro);

        textViewLocalizacao = findViewById(R.id.textViewLocalizacao);
        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView6 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        //Informaçoes de latitude e longitude por enquanto deixei invisiveis
        textView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView6.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        instrumentosString = new ArrayList<>();
        estilosString = new ArrayList<>();
        diasString = new ArrayList<>();

        //Incializando fusedLocationProviderClient

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        btnLocalizacaoMusico.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Checar Permissoes

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FinalizaCadastro.this
                        , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //permissão concedida

                    getLocation();

                } else {
                    //Permissão negada
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FinalizaCadastro.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);

                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {


                //Inicializa a localizacao

                Location location = task.getResult();

                if (location != null) {

                    try {

                        //Inicializa geoCoder

                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(FinalizaCadastro.this, Locale.getDefault());

                        //Inicializa lista de endereço


                        List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1
                        );

//Seta a  latitude no textvIEW
                        textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                                "<font color='#6200EE'><b>Latitude :</b><br></font>"
                                        + address.get(0).getLatitude()));
                        //Set Longitude
                        textView2.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                                "<font color='#6200EE'><b>Longitude :</b><br></font>"
                                        + address.get(0).getLongitude()));


                        //seta o país
                        textView4.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                                "<font color='#6200EE'><b>País :</b><br></font>"
                                        + address.get(0).getCountryName()


                        ));

                        //seta o local
                        textView6.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                                "<font color='#6200EE'><b>Local:</b><br></font>"
                                        + address.get(0).getLocality()


                        ));

                        //Seta  o endereço
                        textViewLocalizacao.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                                "<font color='#6200EE'><br></font>"
                                        + address.get(0).getAddressLine(0)


                        ));


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }
                }
            }
        });


//Este
        btnFinalizarCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = mDatabase.getReference("musicos");

                String uuid = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS").format(new Date());
                musico.setInstrumentos(instrumentosString);
                musico.setEstilos(estilosString);

                Task<Void> users = myRef.child("users").child(uuid).setValue(musico);

                users.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Test", e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                users.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d("Test", "s");
                    }
                });

            }
        });


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
        textDataNasc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDataNasc);
        textIdade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textIdade);

        //Evento do Clique do botão calendário
        btnCalendario = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendario);
        btnCalendario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pegaraData();

            }
        });


        // btn_deslogar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeslogar);
        //   btn_deslogar.setOnClickListener(this);


//---------
        Integer[] imgInstrumentos = {
                R.drawable.ic_baixo,
                R.drawable.ic_guitarra,
                R.drawable.ic_bateria,
                R.drawable.ic_vocalista,
                R.drawable.ic_teclado};

        String[] nomeInstrumento = {"baixo", "guitarra", "bateria", "vocalista", "tecladista"};

//----------------------------DIAS-----------------------------

        Integer[] imgDias = {
                R.drawable.ic_calendariodias,
                R.drawable.ic_filtrarmusico,
                R.drawable.ic_foto,
                R.drawable.ic_fotogaleria,
                R.drawable.ic_foto,
                R.drawable.ic_addusuario,
                R.drawable.ic_senha};

        String[] nomeDias = {"segunda", "terça", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sábado", "domingo"};


        //Inicializar arraylist
        dias = new ArrayList<>();

       for (int i = 0; i < imgDias.length; i++) {
           Dia diasMusico = new Dia(imgDias[i], nomeDias[i]);
           dias.add(diasMusico);
        }


        //Layout Horizontal dos dias

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerDias = new LinearLayoutManager(
               FinalizaCadastro.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false
        );

       recyclerViewDias.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerDias);
       recyclerViewDias.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        //inicializa adapter

//Seta o adapater no recyclerviwq
        recyclerViewDias.setAdapter(diasAdapter);


        //Inicializar array
        instrumentos = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imgInstrumentos.length; i++) {
            Instrumento instrumentosMusico = new Instrumento(imgInstrumentos[i], nomeInstrumento[i]);
            instrumentos.add(instrumentosMusico);
        }

        // Layout horizontal dos instrumentos

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                FinalizaCadastro.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false
        );

        recyclerViewInstrumentos.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerViewInstrumentos.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());


        //inicializa adapter
        adapter_instrumentos = new InstrumentosAdapter(FinalizaCadastro.this, instrumentos, this);
        diasAdapter = new DiasAdapter(FinalizaCadastro.this, dias,this);
        //Configuração RecyclerView dos Instrumentos
        recyclerViewInstrumentos.setAdapter(adapter_instrumentos);



    }
    //VER


    //    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Aqui é para pegar a data do calendário referente ao nascimento do usuário

    private void pegaraData() {
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);


        //Criação do Objeto aqui eu pego as datas e exibo para o usuario

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(FinalizaCadastro.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                        textDataNasc.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
                        //Calcular idade

                        calcularIdade(dayOfMonth, month, year);


                    }
                }, ano, mes, dia);

        datePickerDialog.show();
    }


    //Calcula idade
    private void calcularIdade(int diaNasc, int mesNasc, int anoNasc) {

        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        int diaAtual = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int mesAtual = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int anoAtual = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        //Verifinado a idade do músico

        int idade = anoAtual - anoNasc;

        if (mesNasc > mesAtual) {
            idade--;
        } else if (mesAtual == mesNasc) {
            if (diaNasc > diaAtual) {
                idade--;
            }
        }

        textIdade.setText("Sua idade: " + idade);
    }

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Vai informar que o usuário selcionou um instrumento
    @Override
    public void addInstrumento(Instrumento instrumento) {

        // Verifica se o item clicado já existe eu removo e sai da função
        for (String item : this.instrumentosString) {
            if (item.equals(instrumento.getNomeInstrumento())) {
                this.instrumentosString.remove(item);
                return;
            }
        }

        initInstrumentosListString();
        this.instrumentosString.add(instrumento.nomeInstrumento);
    }

    private void initInstrumentosListString() {
        if (instrumentosString == null) {
            instrumentosString = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

//---------------------FAZENDO ESTILOS

    public void addEstilo(Estilo estilo) {

        // Verifica se o item clicado já existe eu removo e sai da função
        for (String item : this.estilosString) {
            if (item.equals(estilo.getNomeEstilo())) {
                this.estilosString.remove(item);
                return;
            }
        }

        initEstilosListString();
        this.estilosString.add(estilo.nomeEstilo);
    }

    private void initEstilosListString() {
        if (estilosString == null) {
            estilosString = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    //------------------------DIAS

    public void addDia(Dia dia) {

        // Verifica se o item clicado já existe eu removo e sai da função
        for (String item : this.diasString) {
            if (item.equals(dia.getNomeDias())) {
                this.diasString.remove(item);
                return;
            }
        }

        initDiasListString();
        this.diasString.add(dia.nomeDias);

    }

    private void initDiasListString() {
        if (diasString == null) {
            diasString = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

MEU ITEM DIAS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewDias"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="10dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageCalendarioEnsaio"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="66dp"
            android:src="@drawable/foto" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDiasSemana"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Dias"
            android:textSize="10sp">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MINHAS CLASSE DIA

```
package com.example.tocacomigo;

public class Dia {
        String nomeDias;
        Integer imgDias;


        public Dia(Integer imgDias, String nomeDias) {
            this.imgDias = imgDias;
            this.nomeDias = nomeDias;
        }

        public Integer getImgDias() {
            return imgDias;
        }

        public String getNomeDias() {
            return nomeDias;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você esta setando o adapter antes de iniciar ele.

Na linha 325 você seta o `diasAdapter` no `recyclerViewDias`:

```
//Seta o adapater no recyclerview
recyclerViewDias.setAdapter(diasAdapter);
```

Porém o adapter só é iniciado na linha 348. Tente iniciar a classe `diasAdapter` antes de setar ela no `recyclerViewDias`.